# Convert an alpha-numeric URL into a static human "pretty" link?

Tags: html, url, content-management-system

When a user to our site filters attributes for a product our CMS generates a very long URL like this:

```
[our domain] .com/bcc.15569_bpt.46#/bt=37&bcs=2&t=2&bpt=46&s=10&l=1&sb=136
```

This URL was created when a user has searched (filtered) for specific product attributes (like color, size, etc) and hence the long URL

I believe that this URL is generated from "GET" requests...

My question is - does anyone know if this URL can be made to look "pretty" and human-readable?

How would I go about discovering if this is even possibe?

Maybe .htaccess could be a solution?

Comment: There is a lot of information in that URL about which filters were chosen and what the values for the filters are.   How are you even proposing that it be made "prettier"?  I'm not sure that can be done without removing information from the URL.  What would the point be anyway?  With that many things in the URL, it is well beyond the point where a user might be able to memorize it, let alone type it accurately.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller my POV is entirely driven by SEO

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se].  This question has already been asked and answered there: [SEO-friendly way to pass multiple values in a URL parameter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132570/seo-friendly-way-to-pass-multiple-values-in-a-url-parameter)

Comment: I'm curious - why vote on closing this? It would do zero harm in keeping it online and indeed your referred URL in your reply does indeed help answer the question. Keeping it online just widens the net to help people - if this question gets indexed and they are referred to your reply then - surely - all good? I see the logic of de-duplication of course, but not sure I agree about lessening the reach...